# How to make the forest at the center?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, forest, trees

I want to put the forest at the center

here is my code:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

%---\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\title{The principal title: hello !}


\begin{document}
%---\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\scalebox{.9}{


\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}P{45mm}@{}}
        },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
        }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

            }

\caption{My figure}
\end{figure*}




this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\end{document}
```

thanks

Comment: Your code yields tons of error messages. Once I make your code compilable, it is centered. You need to add `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}`, use `align={@{}P{45mm}@{}}` and better remove `\makeatlettter` and remove `\maketitle` when you do not specify the necessary data.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you, I applied your remarks however it still not at the center. I updated the code here

Comment: Then there seems to be something wrong with your TeX installation. Or do you mean vertically centered? BTW, I would avoid all this `\scalebox` stuff. Just decrease the text width. I also do not understand the purpose of `align={@{}P{45mm}@{}}`, you can achieve this with `text width=45mm,align=center,inner xsep=0pt`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, actually it works great when `\scalebox` is removed, but I have many leaves and it takes much space

Answer (score 1):

works fine --suggest add things one by on

[image]

```
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just 


%\begin{figure*}[!]
\centering
%\scalebox{.9}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
%    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
        },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
%  drop shadow,
        }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}



%\caption{My figure}
%\end{figure*}




this is just a text.this is just a text.th
\end{document}
```

Comment: when I add more text, the forest shows in one column, how to solve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- it is not clear, what is your problem, so my answer is based on guessing that you like to have tree diagram showed on image in your question
- please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small (as possible) document, which reproduce your problem. It should in preamble load only to problem relevant package and contain only relevant your definition. Al other just distract reader from your problem.
- `forest` code can be simplified, if you load package with option `edges` and in code use option `forked edge` (see MWE below)
- code is more clear, if you structure settings in `for tree`, for example first all related to nodes shape style and then all related to tree structure.
- in MWE is added package `stfloats` which enable that figure can be on the same page where is inserted (if there is enough space for it)
- for dummy text is added package `lipsum`

Below are two suggestion:

- diagram, which can be fit in one column (it has smaller distances between nodes, smaller font size and nodes width different width in bottom level):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners=2pt, 
    fill=white, drop shadow,
    font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    where n children=0{text width=6em}{text width=4em},
    text centered,
% tree
    grow=east,
    anchor=west,
    forked edge,    % for forked edge
    s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
    l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
 fork sep = 3mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
       }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
    \caption{My figure}
    \label{fig:forest-1}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

- diagram, which occupy width of two columns (it has bigger distances between nodes, normal size font and different width of top node):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners=2pt, 
    fill=white, drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
    where n children=2{minimum width=1em}{text width=11em},
    text centered,
% tree
    grow=east,
    anchor=west,
    forked edge,    % for forked edge
    s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
    l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
 fork sep = 3mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
       }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
    \caption{My figure}
    \label{fig:forest-1}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My versions:

Showing forest in one column:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

%---\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\title{The principal title: hello !}


\begin{document}
%---\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\begin{figure}[!t]
%\begin{center}
\centering
%\scalebox{.7}{

{\footnotesize
\begin{forest}
/tikz/every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}P{23mm}@{}}
                            },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\footnotesize,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
        }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
}
          %  }
%\end{center}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}




this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\end{document}
```

Showing forest in two column:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

%---\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\title{The principal title: hello !}


\begin{document}
%---\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\begin{figure*}[!t]
%\begin{center}
\centering
%\scalebox{.7}{

{\footnotesize
\begin{forest}
/tikz/every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}P{35mm}@{}}
                            },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\footnotesize,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
        }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
}
          %  }
%\end{center}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure*}




this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: (i) Your forest is not in one (text) column but over two (ii) Diagram is not he same as is written in your question and reproduced in @jsbibra's answer (+1). Please, clarify your question and correct all errors in in it. Also presented code make minimal (most of preamble is not relevant to your problem and just distract attention of reader from your problem))