# How to reduce the size of forest?

Tags: forest, trees, resize

I have a forest with many leaves and It took the whole page. I want to reduce its size. I tried `\scalebox` but it doesn't work, it goes out of the page

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

%---\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\title{The principal title: hello !}


\begin{document}
%---\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\begin{figure*}[!t]
%\begin{center}
\centering
%\scalebox{.7}{


\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}P{45mm}@{}}
        },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
        }
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
    [Class Diagram]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

          %  }
%\end{center}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure*}




this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue was solved, thank you This [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539042/211853) could be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `\footnotesize` in a group with the tree

```
{\footnotesize
  \begin{forest}
    ...
  \end{forest}%
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the font for every node in the tree's preamble using

```
/tikz/every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
```

Comment: Thank you, I used both of them