# Tree does not show correctly

Tags: forest, trees

I have a tree in 2-column display, it doesn't shows correctly. There are some errors that I no know how to resolve them

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[templates]{genealogytree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\RN}[1]{
\textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
}
\modulolinenumbers[5]


\begin{document}

this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.



\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
{\footnotesize

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
         },
draw,
font=\sffamily\bfseries,
edge path={
   \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
l sep=10mm,
tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
inner color=white,
outer color=white,
rounded corners=2pt,
drop shadow,
}
[level x
   [level x
      [level x
         [level x]
         [level x]
         [level x]

  ]
 ]
[level y
   [level y]
[level y
    [level y
        [level y]
    ]
    [level y]
    [level y]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
}
\end{figure*}

this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


 \end{document}
```

thanks

Comment: Please, can you put a compilable MWE thanks? Missing `\documentclass` and peraphs others packages (?).

Comment: @Sebastiano, the ' \documentclass ' is not missing. In fact, I trying to find what are the missing packages. Thank you !

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539042/197451

Comment: duplicate -- ?? -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538929/how-to-make-the-forest-at-the-center/539046#539046

Comment: @jsbibra, these links are for Horizontal trees. I want them vertically here. thanks

Comment: @Lee Excuse me, then.

Comment: @Sebastiano, no problem at all. you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer in the sense that the code here should not be used as an example that is used by others. There are two issues:

1. You have an empty line in the `forest`.
2. You did not define the `C` column type.

Fixing these produces a code that runs without errors.

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[templates]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\RN}[1]{
\textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
}
\modulolinenumbers[5]


\begin{document}

this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.



\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
{\footnotesize

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
         },
draw,
font=\sffamily\bfseries,
edge path={
   \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
l sep=10mm,
tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
inner color=white,
outer color=white,
rounded corners=2pt,
drop shadow,
}
[level x
   [level x
      [level x
         [level x]
         [level x]
         [level x]
  ]
 ]
[level y
   [level y]
[level y
    [level y
        [level y]
    ]
    [level y]
    [level y]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
}
\end{figure*}

this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a
text.


\end{document}
```

However, your tree is way too wide. This is something that one has to solve, maybe with the `landscape` mode.

Comment: Thank you Schrödinger's cat